# QTreeView "docking" items

Tags: c++, qt5

Using QTreeView together with QAbstractItemModel. The QTreeView looks like this:

item_a
   sub_item_1
item_b
   sub_item_2
item_c
   sub_item_3
item_d
   sub_item_4

We would like to separate item_a\item_b and item_c\item_d. How can we "dock" the first two items to the top of the QTreeView and "dock" the last two items to the bottom of the QTreeView?

item_a
   sub_item_1
item_b
   sub_item_2

-- space depending on size of QTreeView --

item_c
   sub_item_3
item_d
   sub_item_4

Looked at QStyledItemDelegate but could see how to accomplish the task using the class. Any ideas?

Comment: I see two options here : 1 - use two QTreeViews; 2 - use dummy item between item_b and item_c, size of which will be changed dynamically. I'd use the first variant, because it is the easiest one, also you can use one model for many views.

Comment: For #1, do you use setRowHidden to setup QTreeView correct info? How do you handle one selection model across two QTreeViews?